# How can I get these four columns to be written concatenated into another column?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, concatenation

How can I get these four columns to be written concatenated into another column?

```
SELECT CONCAT( calle,  ' ', num,  ', ', colonia,  ', ', cd ) AS geoco
FROM TABLE_1
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_1
SET geoco = CONCAT( calle,  ' ', num,  ', ', colonia,  ', ', cd )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TABLE_1 
set col_to_update = CONCAT( calle, ' ', num, ', ', colonia, ', ', cd ) 
where ...
```